# How to show tooltip for disabled radiobutton in group of radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a list of radio buttons. In which one should be disabled based on condition. For that particular disabled button only I need to show the tooltip.

[image]

```
import {Tooltip} from '@mui/material'; 
   
           <Tooltip
              title={
                <div>
                  <span>Tooltip message</span>
                  <a
                    href={links}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    style={{ color: 'blue', textDecoration: 'underline' }}
                  >
                    linktext
                  </a>
                </div>
              }
              arrow
              placement="bottom-start"
            >
             
                <RadioListComponent
                  row
                  aria-labelledby="classname"
                  defaultValue="one"
                  sx={{//style } }}
                  items={listArray.map((option) => ({
                    ...option,
                    sx: {
                      ...option.sx,
                      pointerEvents: option.value === 'two' && !enabled ? 'none' : 'auto',
                      opacity: option.value === 'two' && !enabled ? 0.5 : 1,
                    },
                  }))}
                  {...field}
                />
            </Tooltip>
```

RadioListComponent

```
const Radio = forwardRef((props: RadioProps, ref: RefType) => {
const { items, action, ...radioGroupProps } = props;
return n (
  <MuiRadioGroup {...radioGroupProps} ref={ref}>
  {items.map((item, index) => (
    <FormControlLabel
      value={item.value}
      onClick={action}
      control={<MuiRadio aria-label={item.label} />}
      label={
        <>
              <Typography component="span" sx={{//style }}>
                {item.label}
              </Typography>
            </Tooltip>
          <Typography component="span" sx={{ //style }}>
            {item.label}
          </Typography>
        </>
      }
      sx={item.sx}
    />
  ))}
</MuiRadioGroup>
);
});
```

Now the problem is that while hovering any radio button the tooltip getting displayed is not required. only the disabled one only needs this tooltip.

How to fix it? Any solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the package you are using for ```<Tooltip>``` and ```<RadioListComponent>``` ?

Comment: @Harry updated! Please refer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `listArray` has options and its respective values with enabled prop. You can modify your `MuiRadioGroup` component in the following way:

```
{
   item.enabled ? <FormControlLabel
      value={item.value}
      onClick={action}
      control={<MuiRadio aria-label={item.label} />}
      label={
        <>
              <Typography component="span" sx={{//style }}>
                {item.label}
              </Typography>
            </Tooltip>
          <Typography component="span" sx={{ //style }}>
            {item.label}
          </Typography>
        </>
      }
      sx={item.sx}
    /> :      <Tooltip
              title={
                <div>
                  <span>Tooltip message</span>
                  <a
                    href={links}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    style={{ color: 'blue', textDecoration: 'underline' }}
                  >
                    linktext
                  </a>
                </div>
              }
              arrow
              placement="bottom-start"
            >
                   <FormControlLabel
      value={item.value}
      onClick={action}
      control={<MuiRadio aria-label={item.label} />}
      label={
        <>
              <Typography component="span" sx={{//style }}>
                {item.label}
              </Typography>
            </Tooltip>
          <Typography component="span" sx={{ //style }}>
            {item.label}
          </Typography>
        </>
      }
      sx={item.sx}
    />
    </Tooltip>

}
```

Excuse the formatting if you get the idea what I mean. Also there are many ways shorten the code.